# How to define a view on a table that has a date column to add a new column to indicate that tuple wasn't present at previous dates

Tags: sql-server

Say schema is

```
EntryDate
,Dim1
,Dim2
,Dim3
```

And I want to create a view

```
EntryDate
,Dim1
,Dim2
,Dim3
,IsNew
```

Where IsNew is true if that tuple of Dim1,Dim2,Dim3 hadn't existed for earlier EntryDate.

Not concerned about performance as I will eventually regenerate the base table. But I want to test some business logic beforehand using a view.

Comment: So what's stopping you doing what you're trying to achieve? Why isn't your attempt working? What was that attempt?

Comment: Just not sure of doing such date diffs in a view's subquery. Here's what I think it should be:

Comment: CREATE VIEW DimsIsNewView
AS
    SELECT
        c.EntryDate
        ,c.Dim1
        ,c.Dim2
        ,c.Dim3
        ,CASE 
            WHEN EXISTS (
               SELECT * from RiskDataCobDealDetail p
               WHERE p.EntryDate < c.EntryDate
                   AND p.Dim1 = c.Dim1
                   AND p.Dim2 = c.Dim2
                   AND p.Dim3 = c.Dim3
            ) THEN 'N'
            ELSE 'Y' 
         END AS IsNew
    FROM DimsBase c

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to use a `ROW_NUMBER`; if the value is `1` it's the first row and is new, if not it isn't new.

```sql
SELECT EntryDate,
       Dim1,
       Dim2,
       Dim3,
       CONVERT(bit,CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Dim1, Dim2, Dim3 ORDER BY EntryDate ASC) WHEN 1 THEN 1
                        ELSE 0
                   END) AS IsNew
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```